# Falha na aquisição de data source com JPA e EclipseLink

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, glassfish

Quando coloco para o `persistence.xml` usar um resource JNDI configurado no próprio Glassfish não dá erro. Mas quando é para pegar do arquivo `glassfish-resource.xml` dá o seguinte erro:

> Informações:   [EL Info]: 2014-07-09 12:24:19.019--ServerSession(1076034183)--EclipseLink, 
>   version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b
>   Informações: 
>   [EL Severe]: ejb: 2014-07-09 12:24:19.038--ServerSession(1076034183)
>   Exception [EclipseLink-7060] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
>   Exception Description: Cannot acquire data source [jdbc/Banco].
>   Internal Exception: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'jdbc/Integracao' in SerialContext
>   [myEnv= java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Banco not found]

Segue os arquivos usados:

**glassfish-resource.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
    <jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" associate-with-thread="false" connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" connection-leak-reclaim="false" connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" connection-validation-method="auto-commit" datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" fail-all-connections="false" idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" is-connection-validation-required="false" is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" lazy-connection-association="false" lazy-connection-enlistment="false" match-connections="false" max-connection-usage-count="0" max-pool-size="32" max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" name="pool_de_conexao" non-transactional-connections="false" pool-resize-quantity="2" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" steady-pool-size="8" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" wrap-jdbc-objects="false">

          <!-- Propriedades da conexão -->          

    </jdbc-connection-pool>
    <jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="jdbc/Banco" object-type="user" pool-name="pool_de_conexao"/>
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="br.com.app-1.0-SNAPSHOTPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>jdbc/Banco</non-jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por alguma razão, desconhecida, o arquivo contendo o JDBC Resource não está sendo implantado junto com a aplicação.

Nesse caso, então, adicionar propriedades de conexão ao arquivo **persistence.xml** resolve o problema da conexão.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="br.com.app-1.0-SNAPSHOTPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
      <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://*******" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="*******" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="*******" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 1):

Como está a estrutura de seu projeto ? é um `.war`, `.ear` ou `.jar` ? onde você está colocando o `glassfish-resource.xml` ?

Não entendo muito de Glassfish, mas o problema é genérico:
basicamente seu arquivo do datasource não está entrando junto com sua aplicação no deploy.
Verifique no log de inicialização, se o jndi está sendo registrado.

Arquivos de recursos devem estar localizados na pasta `META-INF` (para .ear ou .jar) ou na `WEB-INF` (para .war) para que seja feito o deploy no container.

Fora isso, porque você está usando o tipo de transação como `RESOURCE_LOCAL` em um application server ? deixe o server cuidar do trabalho pesado pra você, de uma olhada qui [**AQUI**](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/don_t_use_jpa_s).

Caso não resolva seu problema, atualize essas informações para podermos ajudar melhor.

Comment: Por alguma razão, que não sei, o arquivo glassfish-resource.xml não está indo junto com o app. E sobre o JTA ao invés de RESOURCE_LOCAL é uma boa opção, porém não funciona com a solução que encontrei.